# Xcode how to get iTunes track info from iTunes, specifically comments?

Tags: import, comments, itunes

Can I input the user comments on tracks in iTunes into my App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments, it sounds like you're not actually on Mac, but iOS, and you're not actually trying to access comments from iTunes, but from the iOS music library.

If so:

```
NSString *comments = [currentItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyComments];
```

This will get you the comments in the iOS music library. However, there's no guarantee that the device will sync comments for any track that it syncs from iTunes (or purchases from the Store, or downloads from Match), so you may very well get nothing. In that case, there's nothing you can do about it.

You cannot directly get the comments from iTunes, because you are not connected to iTunes.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I am programming for iOS connecting my music player to the iTunes library to import tunes or playlist. I was trying to see if it was possible to import the comments associated with the songs that someone could have entered in iTunes before syncing with an iDevice and running my music player app.

Comment: You are *not* connecting your player to the iTunes library, you are connecting it to the iOS music library. It's not the same thing. Even if the device does sync to iTunes (which isn't mandatory), it doesn't necessarily copy over all of the data from iTunes. If the comments are copied over, the code above will get them. If they aren't, there's no way to get them, because they're not there to get.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very ambiguous.

On Mac, the user comments are available as the `comment` property on any `track` object. On Windows, they're available as the result of the `Comment` method on any `IITTrack` object.

So, assuming you already know how to access a track:

AppleScript:

```
comment of theTrack
```

Python with either ScriptingBridge or appscript on Mac:

```
theTrack.comment()
```

Python with PyCOM on Windows:

```
theTrack.Comment()
```

ObjC with either ScriptingBridge or appscript:

```
[theTrack comment];
```

And so on.

If you don't know how to access a track, you need more fundamental help than this (and you need to tell us whether you're on Windows or Mac, which language and library you want to use, etc.), but here's a complete py-appscript example that prints out the comments of the every track in the library:

```
from appscript import *
print('\n'.join(app('iTunes').tracks.comment()))
```

If you're not scripting iTunes, but parsing its XML library plist file, each track is a `dict` under `Tracks`. If a track has user comments, they're a string with the key `Comments`. Again, if you don't already know how to parse this XML file, you've got more fundamental problems. But here's a trivial example again:

```
from Foundation import NSDictionary
d = NSDictionary.dictionaryWithContentsOfFile_('/Users/me/Music/iTunes/iTunes Library.xml')
print('\n'.join(t.get('Comments', '') for t in d['Tracks'].values()))
```

Comment: I am using a Mac and programming with Xcode. I know how to access the track titles, play times, etc. but do not know how to access the comments? Thank you.

Comment: There are many different languages you could be using in Xcode, and multiple different ways you could be accessing the track titles in each language. If you tell me which way you're using (or at least just give me the line of code you use to get the title for a given track), I can show you how to do the same for comments.

Comment: This is how I get the track title:MPMediaItem *currentItem = [musicPlayer nowPlayingItem];
  NSString *titleString = [currentItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
 titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",titleString];

Comment: There is no such class as `MPMediaItem` on Mac. There is such a class is iOS, but there's no such thing as iTunes in iOS (well, there is, but it's the store app not the player), and you explicitly said you're using Mac. So, what you're trying to do doesn't even make sense. If you didn't mean what you said, see my other answer.